# Split comma value and insert data c#

Tags: c#

I want to insert data with for loop by a split comma here comma values will be treat as a column value and semicolon will treat as a new row:

```
string st = "test1,test2;test3,test4;";

for(int i = 0; i < col.length; i++)
{
    // insert into tableName (col,col) values(test1,test2);
}
// further it should loop like test3,test4...
```

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: I don't see any connection to a database, nor any attempt to actually insert data. What have you tried?

Comment: coonection to dabase is everything is correct

Comment: But where is it? Where are you attempting to input the data? There is NO attempt

Comment: That string will gerate 4 fields for only 2 columns. I dont know exactually what do you want. But use a .Split(); and loop result in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This:

```
foreach (var row in st.Split(";"))
{
   var cols = row.Split(",");
   var col1 = cols[0];
   var col2 = cols[1];
   /// your operation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.Split(''); to seperate out the way you want, and then add it to your database or what have you.

```
List<string> rows = "test1,test2;test3,test4;".Split(";");

for(var i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
{
  List<string> columns = rows[i].Split(',');
  for(var x = 0; x < columns.Count; x++)
  {
      database.add(columns[x]);
  }
}
```

Without knowing WHAT you're adding it to, we can't help much more than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.Split()

```
     string input = "test1, test2; test3, test4";
     var splitResult= Regex.Split(input, "; ");
     foreach (data in splitResult) 
       var finalResul= Regex.Split(data, ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data with Linq:

```
string st = "test1,test2;test3,test4;";

var data = st.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Split(','))
    .Select(s => new { col1 = s[0], col2 = s[1]});
```